# Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource in Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-12

Migrating from android 30 to the android 31 version, I am trying to connect to the paired Bluetooth device in my app.

But, I am facing an issue when I tried to get the paired device list.

```kotlin
val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices

    pairedDevices?.forEach { device ->
        if(device.address.lowercase() == configHelper.bluetoothAddress.lowercase()){
            bluetoothDevice = device
            paymentTerminalName = device.name
            paymentTerminalMAC = device.address // MAC address
            UUIDFromPaymentTerminal = device.uuids[0].uuid // UUID specifies the service that the the server provides
        }
    }
    if(bluetoothDevice == null){
        //payment terminal is not paired yet
        throw ex
    }
    socket = bluetoothDevice!!.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUIDFromPaymentTerminal)
    //cancel discovery, otherwise it slows down the connection process
    bluetoothAdapter!!.cancelDiscovery()
    (socket!! as BluetoothSocket).connect()
```

I am getting the below error,

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10414, packageName =
com.test.app, attributionTag = null, token =
android.os.BinderProxy@8a4f87d, next = null }: AdapterService
getBondedDevices
```

I have added bluetooth permission to my manifest file,

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
```

Let me know where am I missing to get the paired device in kotlin 1.5.0

Comment: you have need to get runtime permission in android 12

Answer (score 2):

The `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT & BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permissions are runtime permissions, these permissions have to be asked during the runtime of your application.

The BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission should be asked before you scan for devices and the BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission should be asked before you connect to a device.

An example of a permission requester for an single permission within the Fragments architecture:

```
val requestConnectPermission: ActivityResultLauncher<String> =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { permissionGranted ->
        if (permissionGranted) {
            // connect to device
        }
    }
```

An example of a requester for multiple permissions within the Fragments architecture:

```
val permissionRequester: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>> = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        if (permissions.values.all { it }) {
            // connect to device
        }
    }
```

To handle a single permission request within an Composable is slightly different, you can do the following:

```
val permissionRequester =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { granted ->
         if (granted) {
             // connect to device
         }
    }

 requestConnectPermission?.launch(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
```

And for multiple permissions at once:

```
val permissionRequester =
    rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        if (permissions.values.all { it }) {
            // connect to device
        }
    }
```

Before you should use such a permission launcher you should check if the user has already accepted the permissions. If not you can launch a request. An example to launch a single permission request:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // connect to device
} else {
    permissionRequester.launch(BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)
}
```

And if you want to launch multiple permission requests at once you can do this:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), BLUETOOTH_SCAN) == PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       // connect to device
    } else {
       permissionRequester.launch(arrayOf(BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, BLUETOOTH_SCAN))
}
```

More info about permissions can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: rememberLauncherForActivityResult - in this function what will you handle, and what will its returns?

Comment: In this function the result of the permission request is returned, so here you can check if the permission is granted or not. If the permission is granted you can initiate te connect logic.